# which function to use in order to remove an object from an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I'm trying to loop through to match for a specific value, if found delete that object else return false. Below is the code:

```
array: [{
 obj1:{
    id: null,
    name:'test',
    address: '6857346jfhbdjshb'
 },
  obj12:{
    id: 678346,
    name:'test',
    address: '63784hgj'
 },
  obj13:{
    id: null,
    name:'test',
    address: 'tevhgvd'
 },
  obj15:{
    id: 65847,
    name:'test',
    address: 'djhvwe677ghdgv'
   },
  obj18:{
    address: ""
   }
}]
```

js:

```
    for (var obj in array){
       if (array[obj].address === "63784hgj" || array[obj].address === "djhvwe677ghdgv" ||array[prop].address === "")
     {
     array[obj].destroy(); //equivalent to array[1].destroy() (destroy, delete,remove,hide, pop none of them work)
     }
  }
```

I'm not sure which function is the correct one to remove object from array.

Comment: Hard to believe that you came up with zero results for this in a web search

Comment: There is only one element in your array, so looping over it is not going to accomplish very much. You want to loop over the keys in the object which is the single element. Once you find a key you want to delete, you can delete it in [the standard way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Comment: *I have an array of objects that im trying to loop through to match for a specific value,* No you don't. You have an array containing a **single** element, which is an object containing multiple properties.

Comment: Actually, this is not about removing an array element (and therefore is not a duplicate of questions about that). It's about removing object properties (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently want to filter out certain properties from the single element of your array, which is an object, containing subobjects, when the `address` property of the subobject matches one or more string values.

Extract the first element of the array, then loop over its properties with a `for...in` loop. If the subproperty matches, delete the property with `delete`.

```
function filterproc(array) {
  var o = array[0];

  for (var k in o) 
    if (o[k].address === "....")
      delete o[k];
}
```

To match against multiple possibilities, consider using `indexOf`, which checks if an array contains some value:

```
if (['63784hgj', ...].indexOf(o[k]) !== -1) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is what [toranaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo) described in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37982118/3078890) then nothing to do with mine. :( **`(inform me to delete mine)`**

If you want a function which returns the new value do this:

```
var forbiddenAddressList = ['', '63784hgj', 'djhvwe677ghdgv'];
var newArray = myArray.filter(i => forbiddenAddressList.indexof(i.address) === -1);
```

another way:

```
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    if(forbiddenAddressList.indexof(i.address) === -1)
        newArray.push(myArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

So if what you're asking is to loop through an array of objects, and if the value of a property is found then delete the object it belongs to, then this is what I came up with.

```
var array = [
        {id: null,name:'test',address: '6857346jfhbdjshb'},
        {id: 678346,name:'test',address: '63784hgj'},
        {id: null,name:'test',address: 'tevhgvd'},
        {id: 65847,name:'test',address: 'djhvwe677ghdgv'},
        {address: ""}
    ];

for (var obj in array){
       if (array[obj].address === "63784hgj" || array[obj].address === "djhvwe677ghdgv" || array[obj].address === "")
        {
            array.splice(obj, 1);
        }
    }
```

I modified your array of objects, but everything except Obj1, Obj2 etc. remains because arrays are already indexed, thus array[0] refers to Obj1. Also in your if statement you had array[prop] which is undefined, so be sure to change it in your code. This worked for what I think you were trying to do, so let me know if it helps.

Comment: If you delete an item from array, it's place will filled with `undefined` so the better way is to filter items you want or push then to new array.

Comment: The poster could also use array.splice(obj, 1) if they do not want to leave undefined arrays in there.

Comment: Then the correction of your answer would be to change delete with splice.

Comment: Good call mortezaT.